# Python Import Error but in the same directory

Tags: python, import

This may seem like a easy question, but I have tried my best to figure it out.

I have two files:

Car.py and Dealership.py

They are in the same directory. Dealership.py contains a bunch of methods and another class that I would like to use in Car.py. The class name is "worker".

So in Car.py I write at the top of the file:

```
from Dealership import worker
```

I have also tried:

```
import Dealership
```

I continually get this error:

```
 No module named Dealership
```

I can't understand why. As far as I know, and according to pydocs, I am writing the imports correctly, and the files are in the same directory.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: What version of Python are you using? If you are using 3.x, you will need to use absolute imports — see http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/

Comment: I went to help>About>IDLE... I am using 2.73

Comment: @pswaminathan thanks for that suggestion. It got me thinking about versions. I went ALL the way back and tried out the python 2.3 grammar in eclipse and everything was fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the current directory to the sys.path, so that the Python will try to find the module here.

```
import sys
sys.path.append(".")
```

Comment: @LearnLanguages96 Yes, you could replace it with your file directory. If you do not, it should ALSO works. Because "." means the current direcotry.

Comment: That didnt work. I have import sys then sys.path.append(".") then from Dealership import worker. Could it be a bug?

Comment: Okay, so when I put worker in a file by itself, it worked. The only thing I can think is that I am not allowed to have multiple methods that are not within a class in python? For example, in Dealership I have def method, def method...class worker. When I have a file with Class worker only, it imports.

Comment: @LearnLanguages96 On my PC, it is working. You could try to make an empty file "\_\_init\_\_.py" in the same folder, and try again. I tried in Python 2.6, 2.7, and 3.3. All works~

Comment: Yeah, I did that. It still didn't work. Thanks for the help though

Comment: @LearnLanguages96 I am sorry, I did not help much.

Comment: No problem! That solution may help in the future.